# Mann-Whitney or K-W?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test

I am studying a biomarker in cancer, and I want to know if there are differences related with the location of the cancer (head and neck, lung or cervix).
When I do the Kruskall-Wallis test, I find a statistically significant p. Deeper, If I click on the model viewer of SPSS, I can see the comparison between pairs (head and neck and lung, head and neck and cervix, cervix and lung....) with a significance and an adjusted significance, which are very different.

On the other hand, if I decide to compare pairs using Mann-Whitney, I get a different significance.

My questions are:

Which are the different bettwen K-W significance and the adjusted one, in the comparison between pairs?
And, If I want to check if there are differences between the groups, head and neck and lung, head and neck and cervix, cervix and lung, which test should be performed?

Thanks